# Do i have to make 2 queries to authorize a User in an API?

Tags: mysql, sql, authorization, backend

Lets say i have 2 tables:

`User (id, name)`
`Notes (id, userID, text)`

Now i make a request to my API and supply the User ID. I want to change the text of a certain Note, but only if the User is also the author of that note.

Lets say my User ID is stored in a variable { uID } at the backend.

Do i have to query
`"SELECT userID FROM Notes..."`
first and compare the result to my uID variable and afterwards execute
`"UPDATE Notes..."` ?

It works, but it feels kind of wonky.
Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a where clause:

`UPDATE notes SET ... WHERE userID='uID'`